# Shared Folders Links in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way I can add a local path/link to sharepoint2010 so when my team clicks on that link, it takes them to the shared drive specified in the path? I have tried the links in sharepoint but it does not accept it because the link must start with http. However, the link I want to share is for local shared folder (e.g., D:\Test\Evaluation). Any idea??

Thanks,

Comment: No I haven't. I am not sure what it is actually. can you provide some info about that please.. I am new to SharePoint. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Marek, I meant I have not done the network share before. but I found a solution for this issue and here is what I did:You have to add 'file:///' (without quotes) in front of the shared drive path so SharePoint 2010 can accept it and it is working fine now. Thanks Marek!!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `file:///` be sure to use the UNC form of the server/folder path, like
    file:///\\servername\toplevelfolder\subfolder\

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "file:///"  in front of the shared drive path so SharePoint 2010 can accept it

Answer (score -1):

Our solution is specifically for a SharePoint 2010 Links list which only allows http:// links.  If you want to be able to use a file:// location rather than an http:// location, you'll need to use JQuery. Follow the instructions here:

http://www.sharepointindepth.com/change-hyperlink-field-value-from-http-to-file-on-a-sharepoint-form/

Comment: Could you summarise the link here, in case it breaks?